# Search on Text Datatype field in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server

I am receiving time out errors while doing search operation on `TEXT` datatype column. As per my client request, I cannot use full-text indexes. I have tried with `PATINDEX`, `CHARINDEX` and `LIKE` statements. It is still causing the timed out error.

Can anybody suggest how to do search on `TEXT` datatype?

Thanks,
Eswar

Comment: On `TEXT` and without fulltext index - forget it. Since you're using SQL Server **2008**, you should replace `TEXT` (which is **obsolete** and will be removed soon) with `VARCHAR(MAX)` instead. On such a column, you can easily search

Comment: @marc_s , I have tried with to convert Varchar(MAX) in my query... it is giving timed out error. I have almost 24 lakshs records in my DB. it is not allowing to change datatype.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
WHERE CAST(<text_field> as VARCHAR(max)) LIKE '%something%'
```

However, performance will not be good.   I agree with Marc_s' comment, convert the field in the database if you can...

P.S.   **PatIndex()** and **Charindex()** will also work if you cast the text field